# Error 404 after changing DocumentRoot

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-10.04

I've just installed an Ubuntu Server and transferred my files from another server to this one.
I've copied the files into:

> /var/www/DIRECTORY

When i go to the explorer and put IPADDRESS/DIRECTORY the page loads perfectly.

Of course, i do not want to people access via a directory to my website so i've tried to change the DocumentRoot of my server. So i went to

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

and added the directory after de /var/www

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/DIRECTORY

     <Directory /var/www/DIRECTORY>  
           Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews  
           AllowOverride None  
           Order allow, deny  
           allow from all  
      </Directory>
```

after that, restart apache

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

now, when i go to the explorer i type IPADDRESS

And it automatically redirects me to IPADDRESS/DIRECTORY

And gives me a 404 error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /DIRECTORY/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at I.P.ADD. Port 80
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the root of your apache was /var/www

so previously your redirection worked as the redirection was to `http://YOUR.ADDRESS.COM/DIRECTORY` which found `/var/www/DIRECTORY` - under the DocumentRoot

now you've redefined the DocumentRoot to be `/var/www/DIRECTORY`, the redirection is trying to find `/var/www/DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY`

I don't quite know what you mean by

> Of course, i do not want to people access via a directory to my
>   website so i've tried to change the DocumentRoot of my server.

But the reason for the 404 is altering the DocumentRoot

Comment: Exactly. the problem is that the redirection is trying to find /var/www/DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY. I don't want to generate a redirection.. i want to access http://MY.ADDRESS.COM and see the directory /var/www/DIRECTORY

Comment: ok, so alter the redirection so that it does not include the DIRECTORY.  Normal DNS and web browser behaviour is that it loads the / if no file is specified.   Your DNS (or some other system component) must be adding the DIRECTORY element

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in directive - Multiviews, and AllowOverride none ?
 its except loading .htaccess from you project

```
<Directory /var/www/DIRECTORY/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After apache2 reload, go to http://IPADDRESS/